TokenId generated from flutter Google Sign in package doesn't work in API
In my flutter app I am trying to sign in the user using google and once use the user credentials (tokenid) to authenticate to a wallet named Okto. It does generate the tokenid but doesnt work with the Api. So I was asuuming there is a problem with the API method itself. But when I genrated the tokenId from the 0Auth2.0 playground and passed it into the API, it returned the desired response. I am not sure what I am supposed to do. Do i need to verify my appication in the google cloud, or what else. I am attaching the sign in method code snippet here.
Future<void> _handleGoogleSignIn() async {
    if (_nameController.text.isEmpty || _numberController.text.isEmpty) {
      _showSnackBar('Please enter your name and number.');
      return;
    }

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    try {
      final User? currentUser = _auth.currentUser;

      if (currentUser != null) {
        // User is already signed in, navigate to RewardSplash directly
        _navigateToRewardSplash();
        return;
      }

      final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['email']);
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
          await googleSignIn.signIn();

      if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
            await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
        final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
          idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
        );
        final UserCredential userCredential =
            await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

        final String? idToken = await userCredential.user!.getIdToken();

        if (idToken != null) {
          //pass the generated idtoken to API
          await ApiHandler.authenticateWithToken(idToken);

          // Store the text from the controllers in local variables
          final String name = _nameController.text;
          final String number = _numberController.text;

          // Write data to Firestore
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Contacts').add({
            'name': name,
            'number': number,
          });

          _navigateToRewardSplash();
        } else {
          print("ID Token is null");
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print("Something went wrong. Please try again");
      print(error);
      _showSnackBar('Something went wrong. Please try again');
    } finally {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

I have added all the sha certificates, and still deosnt work. But the id generated from
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ works.

Thats probably because signin gives you an open id connect id token.   to access an api you need an oauth2 access token.    Authorization and authentication are not the same thing

So how can I solve this?

Use oauth2 instead of sign-in

I tried searching for oauth2 implementation in flutter, cant find that works. Can you refer me to smth.

Nope because i have tried on and off for years go get google aouth2 to work with flutter so i could connect to say google calendar.  Never managed to get it to work and no one on the team will make me a sample.  I have asked.  If you get it to work i would love to see the code.
